# CefSharp PDF viewer toolbar button tooltip is in command form instead of normal text

Tags: winforms, chromium, cefsharp

I encountered an issue in cefsharp ver 86.0.241.0, the print/rotate/download button on pdf viewer toolbar is showing command text instead of normal tooltip , please advise how to resolve it ?

[cefsharp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikwmi.png)

Comment: Can you please test with the CEF Sample application, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#cefsharp-vs-chromium-embedded-frameworkcef

Comment: Issue has been opened https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/3081/chromium-85-pdf-viewer-cannot-handle-i18n